# (node.js) Accessing Data from an Excel file inside a open Azure Blob

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, chatbot

I'm trying to access data in node.js from an Excel(csv, xls) file stored inside Azure blob. I'm using follow code in node.js

```
Var workbook = Obj.fromStream(request.get('excel location url'))
```

I'm getting nothing through this.

**Note** : Excel file is open, no authentication required.

Comment: `request.get` is async, you should get the response from hte callback

Comment: also could you post your code ? which libraries are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 'request', 'csvtojson' and 'http' libraries.

Comment: Yeah but could you post a little bit more, so we can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: const request=require('request')
const csv=require('csvtojson')
var http = require('http');
 
var obj = csv(); 
var workbook = obj.fromStream(request.get('~cloud URL~'))
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
console.log(sheet_name_list)

I'm trying to get Excel data from various excel sheets inside cloud excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the [csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) library does not support Excel file, only csv.

Look at the documentation, you can read each line using json, line and csv output.

But your code should look like that:

```
const request=require('request')
const csv=require('csvtojson')
const http = require('http');

csv()
.fromStream(request.get('csv file url'))
.subscribe((json)=>{
    console.log(json)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! **csvtojson** module is working fine now.

Comment: Suppose I have following json getting return from the above CSV file:
var arr = [
    { id: 1, type: 'tree', colors: 'green' },
    { id: 2, type: 'animal', colors: 'yellow'},
    { id: 3, type: 'tree', colors: 'yellow'}
];

I want to search records with 'type'='tree' and 'color' = 'yellow' 
Can we filter the data inside a json?

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to do ? convert a json to csv and filter before writing line ? you need to explain a little bit more.

Comment: Sure, I have a CSV file in the cloud. now I'm able to access that file using **csvtojson**. now I want to make a search in that json result I received. Or is there any suitable to way to filter CSV file and get appropriate result?

Comment: I imagine in the `subscribe` method, you can skip line that does not meet your requirement ?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is working fine.
 if(json.color == 'yellow' && json.type == 'animal')
   {
   console.log(json)
   }

but I want to optimise the code, it will go and check each object in the json. Can we have something fast and efficient than this?

Comment: ro a csv file? using this library ? honestly I don' know